# Is it allowed to sell 3D models of existing brands?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, trademark, fair-use, patents

**Case:** I make 3D models for architecture. Now I made a bundle of IKEA furniture to use in my interior scenes. I do this for clients to give them a visual representation of what a room can be.

Because its very time consuming and the models will be used just a couple of times I want to sell the 3D model (a digital object) on an online market place. What is the legality of this?

Comment: I have added tags because potentially issue of trademark, trade dress and design patents might be implicated, in addition to copyright.

Comment: From a legal POV you almost certainly need to get permission from IKEA before using their branding.

Comment: @ohwilleke thanks could not add them , needed 150 points for it.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to other questions related to selling things based on intellectual property owned by other entities.

Depending on jurisdiction, you will likely need permission from IKEA to use the company name, the term IKEA, product names, designs etc.

IKEA have some history of legal action against parties perceived to be exploiting the IKEA IP.

(Having worked with some big brands I think that in the unlikely event you get permission there may be an approvals process that will make you wish you had made models that weren't based on IKEA's IP or just named them something else.)